# How to desactive ready_only mode or alter it to writable/ready?

Tags: database, postgresql

I set my database to ready_only mode:

set default_transaction_read_only=on;

How to desactive ready_only mode or alter it to writable/ready?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is session parameter, not database. You can set it as default to user though. [Read docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html).

Run `set default_transaction_read_only=off;`
 to swithch it off, eg:

```
t=# set default_transaction_read_only= on;
SET
t=# create table t(i int);
ERROR:  cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction
t=# set default_transaction_read_only= off;
SET
t=# create table t(i int);
CREATE TABLE
```

Also you might want to enable/disable it by default:

```
t=# alter user vao set default_transaction_read_only = on;
```

Comment: I altered my database in production to read only, because we did a migration of system / database. Without deactivate the system.